# How to know if a function is called in C with or without typecasting using gdb or any other tool?

Tags: c, function-pointers

I have a lib from which a function is called using function pointer, the function pointer is set by us in local code.

The issue is, i have assigned the pointer an address of a function which accepts arguments.

and i am suspecting that in lib the function is called without arguments i.e. after type casting it to some other type.

Now, i want to know by using gdb or any other tool weather the function is called with/without type cast. I do not have exact code for the lib but i do have the lib with debug flags.

To explain here is a code snippet:

```
typedef  int (*type1)(void);
typedef int (*type2)(int, int);

int calledFunc (int,int);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    type1 t1;

    t1 = (type1)&calledFunc;

   t1();

   ((type2)t1)(5,6);

  system("PAUSE");  
  return 0;
}

int calledFunc (int a, int b)
{
    printf("Function called=> %d\n",a+b);
    return (a+b);
}
```

In above code how we can deduce using gdb if CalledFunc is called with or without typecasting?

Comment: Casting is a compile-time thing, there's no way of really knowing if there have been casting in run-time. You *could* guess by looking at the arguments, but since the first call is done (wrongly) without arguments it's [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and can't be trusted to work.

Comment: If it's not called from anywhere else, you can break in the function, then step up in the stack and disassemble the caller looking for argument-marshalling operations.  It probably won't be easy if you're not familiar with the calling conventions of your target architecture, though.

Comment: the simple way is to look at the associated .h file for the library.

Comment: as i said function declaration  and definition is in local code, i know what i have created.

Need to know how it is being called from inside the lib

Comment: If you are passing a function pointer as an argument to a function from a third-party library, then that library function's documentation should describe how the pointed-to function should expect to be called.  Ideally, the library function's prototype should contain or reference a prototype for the pointed-to function.  Which, if any, of those "should"s is not the case for you?

Comment: @JohnBollinger yes You are correct, I do have the document which says they called my function with argument, But as the calledFunc is getting garbage in the arguments.

With which i infer that they called my function without argument. (This i am sure because the passed argument was an global variable and it has correct value, which should have passed to calledFunc)

I want to know for sure that they have either wrong code or wrong document.

Comment: If the third-party library is provided in binary form, then it is conceivable that it was built to use different function-calling conventions than your function is compiled to require.  This seems more plausible to me than the library function casting away arguments from a function type.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few steps to do this:

1. Compile the code with `gcc -g codename.c`
2. Run the gdb compiler: `gdb a.out`
3. Set a breakpoint at the function: `b calledFunc`
4. Hit `r` and press enter to run

If the code halts in between, and says something like `Breakpoint 1, calledFunc () at codename.c:x`, that implies that your function has been called. If not, and it merely says something like "Program run sucessfully", then your function has not been called.

If the breakpoint is hit, then take a stack trace to see who the caller is. You can then inspect the caller to see how many parameters they are passing.

Comment: I tried the same thing, and gdb stops for both the calls of the function,  in first case i receive garbage in function argument, while in second time correct value is received.

But using this statement i can't  prove that the function was called wrongly.

Comment: How you can inspect caller? as the gdb shows only line number from where the function was called and current called function & its argument

Comment: Try using `backtrace`

Comment: Yep tried that, but the trace does not differ for the above two calls.

it is same and shows argument in both calls, only difference being the value of arguments.

Comment: He means, use backtrace (`bt`) to find the call point, go to *that* assembly, and inspect it for how/what the caller setup as parameters for your function by examining the disassembly of their code. (which means you need to have a working knowledge of asm).  Even with that working knowledge, given the different potential calling conventions (stdcall, cdecl, fast, etc) this can, and likely will, be a considerable challenge in itself. If you had their source it would be *much* easier (obviously).

Comment: @AnilKumar, the backtrace will show you the call stack.  You can examine the caller by switching to its stack frame (`frame 1`).  If you have debug info for the caller then you should even be able to get a source listing of the call and its vicinity.